# Using emojis in a gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, emoji, cicd

Good morning,

Anyone know how to add emoji in a gitlab pipeline?

In my gitlab-ci.yml file, I tried:

- To add the emoji hard -> it does not work
- To use the unicode of the emoji -> it doesn't work
- Use icon key -> Not working
- Use emojis key -> Not working

Obviously it is possible to do this:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/31581#note_393070368
- https://github.com/yodamad/gitlab-emoji/blob/master/README.md

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share the CI file(s) you've tried and do not work? Where are you wanting to use the emoji? What is "not working" about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emojis are supported. Simply embed the characters directly in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

For example:

```yaml
stages:
  -  build
  -  test

"build  job":
  stage:  build
  script:
    - echo 'build'

"test  job":
  stage:  test
  script:
    - echo 'test'
```

When viewed in GitLab, will show the emojis in the same places stage/job names are usually displayed:

[image: gitlab pipeline]

Answer (score -1):

Given that the issue is 5 years old and there is no recent updates it doesn't look like GitLab supports emojis in the CI/CD Pipeline jobs.

Since you also tried multiple ways to add emojis in the YAML file it confirms that emojis (as of June 2023) are not supported.

*I'm not sure why the GitHub project you shared (second link) doesn't just give you an example of a YAML File. Seems a little suspicious IMO that they want you to click away to another site. *